# Angular ngRoute causes infinity loop and stack overflow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I might be a bit thick here, but I was trying to get ng-view and ngRoute working, and thought I got it all working, but it seems like the whole thing is just looping.

To explain, it's a node server, using express, jade, angular. 
It is set up so that the call should only go to layout, which then opens the routes in ngroute and renders based on that. 
So this is my layout.jade

```
doctype html
html(ng-app="goMinute")
  head
    title= title
    base(href="/")
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  banner
    .banner GoMinut
        p.banner-hit The place for simple meeting minutes

  body(ng-controller='BodyController as app')
      div.content
          ng-view


    script(src='/bower_components/angular/angular.js')
    script(src='/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js')
    script(src='/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js')
    script(src='/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js')
    script(src='/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js')
    script(src='/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/goMinute.js')
```

So far so god, had to set base to something, and / seems to make it happy (not certain if this call this infinity loop 
This then calls goMinute.js which contains the routes, and it SEEMS like they are called

```
(function() {
    var goMinute = angular.module('goMinute', ["ngResource", "ngRoute"]).
        config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
            function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
                $routeProvider
                    .when('/index', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/index',
                        controller: 'IndexController'
                    })
                    .when('/login', {
                        templateUrl: '/partials/login',
                        controller: 'loginController'
                    })

                    .otherwise({redirectTo: "/login"});
            }
        ]
    );
    goMinute.controller('BodyController', function ($scope, $http) {
        console.log("I am body")
    })

    goMinute.controller('IndexController', function ($scope, $http) {
        console.log("This will be Index")
    })

    goMinute.controller('loginController', function ($scope, $http) {
        console.log("This will be login")
    });
})();
```

However, whenever I call the webpage (and idenpendent if I call /index, /login or other. It will go past "I am body" once, thenhit the IndexController about 500 times before throwing a stack overflow. 
Any thoughts?
Oh, and at the time, it generates the layout, but does not seem to output the information in index partial.

Comment: Maybe don't include `angular-route.js` twice?

Comment: did you forgot the forward slash `/` in front of 'partials/index'?

Comment: I should probably have pointed this out, for some reason it requires me to add angular-route.js twice. I do not know why, but if I delete either of them it states that it failed to load ngRoute...

Comment: Tried both with or without / for partials, does not seem to make a difference to the issue.

Comment: I've always wanted to ask a stack overflow question in stack overflow

Comment: I did not think of that, why do I not get a special badge or something for asking a question about stack overflow on ...

Answer (score 0):

After much muching about I think I found the issue (and I was looking in the wrong place).

The problem was not in the router, or at least I don't think so. The problem was with the express router.
I had originally set it up as follows:

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('*', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/partials', partials);
```

Which worked on another site. But I started thinking, what if the loop is caused server side, so removed the * line

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/partials', partials);
```

Which seems to have done the trick. Problem is that I added the * line because some example told me to, so there is of course the chance that I broke it now, and it just seems like it is working.